# Proving that the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ is a subring of $S.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, integral-extensions

Let $R \subset S$ be commutative rings. Prove that the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ is a subring of $S.$

Note that the integral closure of $R$ in $S$ consists of all $x \in S$ that is integral over $R$. And note that an element $x$ is integral over $R$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f(x) \in  R[x]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

I was thinking about using the ordinary subring test for doing that but I was given a hint to use the following Lemma: $x$ is integral over $R$ iff $R[x]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

**My question is:**

**I do not see why I should use this lemma and how it facilitates the steps of the proof, could anyone explain this to me please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You prove that it is a subring by ordinary "subring test" but you use the lemma while doing so. Although in our commutative algebra course we used also the following version of lemma (we actually prove this first to get your lemma but I am not sure whether it is necessary to do it in this order. )

**Lemma 1** $R\subset S$,  $x\in S $ then $x$ is integral over $R$ if $R[x]$ is finitely generated $R-$module.

**Lemma 2** $x$ is integral over $R$ iff there exists finitely generated $R-$module $R'$ such that $R\subset R[x]\subset R'\subset S$

Take $a,b\in S$ integral over $R$. By your lemma $R[a]$ is finitely generated $R$-module. But we can view $R[a]$ simply as a ring so $b$ is integral also over $R[a]$. Hence $R[a][b]$ is finitely generated module over $R[a]$.

Now $R[a][b]=R[a,b]$ as subrings of $S$ (they consist of the same elements) so $R[a,b]$ is also finitely generated as $R-$module.

*Using lemma 2:* Now set $x:=a+b$ and $R':=R[a,b]$. $R'$ is finitely generated $R-$module and $R\subset R[x]\subset R'\subset S$ so by *lemma 2* we conclude that $x$ is integral.

*Commentary* I think that the reason we need to use lemma **2** instead of *ypur version* (lemma 1) is that you can't conclude that $R[a+b]$ is finitely generated from the fact that it is $R-$submodule of finitely generated $R-$module $R[a,b]$. *there are submodules of fin. gen. modules that are not finitely generated* (take ring $R$ as a module over itself it is generated by $1$ but unless it is Noetherian it has ideals that are not finitely generated)

However, in this particular setting, lemma **2**  gives you  that $a+b$ is integral so by lemma **1** is $R[a+b]$ finitely generated $R-$module after all.

Comment: Could you tell me the book that you used the version of the lemma you stated please?

Comment: Sorry if that question is trivial but how can I do that "you can easily check that $R[a][b]=R[a,b]$"?

Comment: Well, it indeed takes some work to show it properly. But t get the idea why it works:  for the moment forget all the stuff about modules. Just 1 take the intersection of all subrings of $S$  containing ring $R$ and elements $a,b$. Now 2 take the intersection of subrings containing $R$ and $a$. This is ring $R[a]$ and take the intersection of all rings containing this ring $R[a]$ and element $b$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reference for the lemma. We have very well written lecture notes (with proofs) in my native language by our lecturer on Commutative Rings. So unless you speak Czech, my reference is no use for you. But I believe that this is basic enough topic, so you should find it in some commutative algebra book.

Comment: Do you recommend a good commutative algebra book?

Comment: In your last line, when you said "so by our version of lemma $a+b$ is integral. " you mean by **your** version of the lemma you stated above in your answer? ..... If so, It is not very clear to me how your lemma will be more appropriate to use at the end than my lemma, could you explain more please?

Comment: I made some edit to my post. I like Eisenbud D. - Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry but I am not sure whether it treats this particular subject. I am not using this book that often

Comment: I can post a question specifically asking for the proof of these two lemmas if you are going to provide me with a thorough proof to them. What is your opinion? can you help me in that?

Comment: But our goal was to prove that $a+b, ab$ are integral not that $R[a+b]$ is finitely generated, so how will that help us in completing the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y\in S$ be integral over $R$. We wish to show that also $x+y$, $xy$ are integral over $R$. By the lemma $R[x]$ is a finite $R$-module. Note that $y$ is surely also integral over $R[x]$, so $R[x][y]$ is a finite $R[x]$-module. Show that this implies that $R[x][y]$ is a finite $R$-module and use the lemma again (we might need a slightly stronger version of the lemma, namely that if $z$ is *contained* in a ring that is a finitely generated $R$-module then $z$ is integral over $R$. This is often proved together with the lemma you cite, if not: the proof is almost identical using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem)

Comment: could you please recommend a book for that proofs?

Comment: So how many times ultimately will I use the lemma?

Comment: This should be covered in any commutative algebra book (that covers integral extensions), for example Matsumura 'Commutative Ring Theory' (Theorem 9.1), Eisenbud 'Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry' (Chapter 4). That lemma is also often covered in algebraic number theory books, for example in the book by Neukirch or the book by Lang.

Comment: The lemma as I stated it or with some modifications?

Comment: The way dmk and I stated it. (Because it is used to conclude e.g. that the set of integral elements form a ring and for that as dmk explained we need the modified version)

Comment: Could you please tell me the proof using Cayley - Hamilton theorem in another answer here?

Comment: In the second book you mentioned I did not see exactly where are the lemmas that we require proved could you clarify this to me please?

Comment: It's in Corollary 4.6. (It's a bit different there. We can apply this here as follows: Let $z\in S$ such that $R[z]$ is contained in a ring $R'$ that is f.g. as and $R$-module. Then we set $N=M=R'$ in that corollary and get that $z$ is integral over $R$)

Comment: what about the proof that $xy$ is integral is that by the same idea used for proving that $x + y$ is integral?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same idea.